# How do I make a function that googles the input from the user, with while loop unless I type 'exit' which breaks it?Do I need to define the variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried making a while loop, however, I can't break it. I am new to programming and maybe I am bitting more than I can chew, but I would be grateful if someone could help me. I am using pywhatkit and I have a problem defining the searching variable.

```
import pywhatkit as pwt

def searching_mode():
    searching = (input(''))
    while True:
        print(f"Searching ...")
        if searching == pwt.search(input('')):
            continue
        else:
            searching == (input('exit'))
            break


searching_mode()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input should be in while loop so it can `continue` execute the input when there's no input or `break` when the input is 'exit'. Try this:

```
import pywhatkit as pwt

def searching_mode():
    while True:
        searching = input('Search for? (type "exit" to exit) : ')
        if 'exit' in searching:
            break
        elif not searching:
            continue
        else:
            print(f'Searching for "{searching}"...')
            pwt.search(searching)

searching_mode()
```

Output:

```
Search for? (type "exit" to exit) : python course
Searching for "python course"...
Search for? (type "exit" to exit) : 
Search for? (type "exit" to exit) : stackoverflow python while loop
Searching for "stackoverflow python while loop"...
Search for? (type "exit" to exit) : exit

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Thank you so much it works!  So the pw.search is in the else part and not in the if definition..Also we don't have a variable outside the while loop... I am such a noob, thank you again!

Comment: No problem. pwt can be in 'if', but for more better logic, pwt in 'else' condition give more eficiency in handling condition, because it's random input value from user, that broader than just 'exit' or empty string. 'Searching' is a variable from input. Just assign one variable and try DRY (don't repeat yourself). No need to add counter or another variable outside the loop in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you can give more information about what you want to achiev and give full script can help better. But you can try setting up a switch to break a loop for example;

```
def searching_mode():
    switch = True:
    searching = (input(''))
    while switch:
        print(f"Searching ...")
        if searching == pwt.search(input('')):
            continue
        else:
            searching == (input('exit'))
            switch = False


 searching_mode()
```

While loop will continue to run if you construct like "while True", so you can setup a condition to break from it. by using

```
while switch:
   if condition1:
     #do something:
   else:
     #do this
     switch = False
     # so next time it
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am trying to google stuff with voice commands using  speech_recognition and pywhatkit. However, I am still building the search part without voice recognition. So I need to set a condition, basically, the switch variable is this condition?

Comment: Also I get a syntaxis error, switch can't be equal to True or False.

Comment: Also, it does not work. After fixing the syntaxis. Do you want the output?